# Does curl option SSLVERSION with value CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 defaults to the latest TLSv1.x supported by server

Tags: php, ssl, curl

For example. Latest supported TLS-protocol on my server is TLS 1.2.

Does setting

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
```

mean that i will use TLS 1.2, and not (for example) TLS 1.1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 will use the best TLS 1.x version supported by both the client and server. Which version this is depends on the capabilities of the underlying TLS stacks and its configuration. While all modern TLS stacks support TLS 1.2 the exact details depend on the specific client and server.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me please, where can i read that? I mean some official documentation.

Comment: @user1011278: I don't think that there is an official documentation which says exactly this. But, the [documentation of CURLOPT_SSLVERSION...](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html) says *CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 - TLSv1.x*.  And by knowing how the TLS handshake works and how the shared protocol is determined (see TLS standard) one can deduce what I said in my answer.